# Poisson-Gamma Hierarchical Model

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs

I am fairly new to Gibbs Sampling and I am trying to build a Gibbs Sampler for a Poisson-Gamma hierarchical model.

In this model, there are $m$ restaurants in a city, with $n_z$ number of observations per restaurant (i.e number of diners per hour), where

$$ Y_{iz} \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_{z}\mu) $$

denotes the $i$th observation from group $z$ and given the following priors

$$ \lambda_{z} \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a,a) $$
$$ \mu \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(k,j) $$

where $\mu$ denotes the overall mean and $\lambda_z$ denotes the ratio between the mean of group $z$ and the overall mean and $\boldsymbol{\lambda} = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ...,\lambda_z)$ with $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_z, \mu$ being independent.

Here is what I don't understand

1. It is explained that $\mu$ is considered the overall mean as $\operatorname{Gamma}(a,a)$ has mean 1 (how can it be inferred from this point?)
2. How do I find the posterior distribution $P(\boldsymbol{\lambda},\mu | \mathbf{y})$ by fixing hyperparams $a,k,j$? I understand the likelihood is $P(\mathbf{y} | \boldsymbol{\lambda},\mu)$ but I have no idea what the formula for prior is.

Answer (score 0):

- The mean of Poisson Distribution $y \sim Poisson(x)$ is $<y>_{Poissson} = x$. The mean of Poisson parameter wrt. Gamma distributions $<\lambda_z \mu>_{Gammas} = <\lambda_z> <\mu>$ factorizes. For general $z \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, the mean is equal to $\alpha/\beta$ which answers your first question.
- Posterior distribution is found by the Bayes theorem:
  $$
  P(\lambda,\mu|y) = \frac{P_{Poisson}(y|\lambda,\mu) P^{(k,j)}_{\Gamma}(\lambda) P^{(a,a)}_{\Gamma}(\mu)}{P(y)}
  $$
  where you need to calculate the evidence function $P(y) = \int d\lambda d\mu P_{Poisson}(y|\lambda,\mu) P^{(k,j)}_\Gamma(\lambda) P^{(a,a)}_{\Gamma}(\mu)$.