# Hyperprior in Gibbs Sampling

Tags: sampling, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs

Following up from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569324/poisson-gamma-hierarchical-model), I have managed to derive the following posterior distributions

$$ \lambda_z | \boldsymbol{y}, \Theta^{(-\lambda_z)} \sim Gamma(a + \sum_{i=1}^{n_z} y_{ij}, \quad a + n_z \mu)$$

$$ \mu | \boldsymbol{y}, \Theta^{(-\mu)} \sim Gamma(k + \sum_{z=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n_z} y_{ij}, \quad j +\sum_{z=1}^{m} \lambda_z n_z)$$

where $\Theta^{(-\mu)}$ represents all parameters except $\mu$ (essentially $\lambda_1,...\lambda_m)$. I have managed to build a Gibbs Sampler when the hyperparameters $a,k,j$ are fixed by the following update formula at the $x$th iteration of Gibbs Sampling.

$$ \mu^{(x)} | \boldsymbol{y}, \Theta^{(-\mu)} \sim Gamma(k^{(x-1)} + \sum_{z=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n_z} y_{ij}, \quad j^{(x-1)} +\sum_{z=1}^{m} \lambda_z^{(x-1)} n_z)$$

$$ \lambda_j^{(z)} | \boldsymbol{y}, \Theta^{(-\lambda_z)} \sim Gamma(a_{shape}^{(x-1)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n_z} y_{ij}, \quad a_{rate}^{(x-1)} + n_z \mu^{(x-1)})$$

where $k^{(x-1)}$ represents the value of $k$ at the $(x-1)$th iteration, likewise for other parameters.

Now, consider that we place a hyperprior on $a$, where $a$ is equally distributed in $\{0.5, 1, 1.5, 2\}$, i.e

$$ P(a = 0.5) = P(a = 1) = P(a = 1.5) = P(a = 2) = 0.25 $$

How do I proceed with Gibbs Sampling to account for this new hyperprior distribution? Am I supposed to model $a$ as a Uniform Distribution along $[0.5, 2]$?

Comment: No, $a$ has a finite distribution over four possible values, with the weights all equal to $1/4$, which means that finding the conditional $P(a|\lambda,\mathbf y)$ is straightforward.

Comment: How do you find the conditional $P(a|\lambda, y)$?

Comment: Apply Bayes' rule.